# Shell Script Invocation Error on XCode 8.3.2 on React-native

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios

I got this Error When I run my ReactNative App

```
/Users/GLB-285/Desktop/ReactProjects/DribbleProject/ios/build/Build/Intermediates/React.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/double-conversion.build/Script-190EE32F1E6A43DE00A8543A.sh: line 3: /Users/GLB-285/Desktop/ReactProjects/DribbleProject/node_modules/react-native/scripts/ios-install-third-party.sh: Permission denied**
```

And In terminal:

```
child_process.js:495
throw err;
^
Error: spawnSync /Users/GLB-285/Desktop/ReactProjects/DribbleProject/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/setup_env.sh EACCES
at exports._errnoException (util.js:1020:11)
at spawnSync (child_process.js:450:20)
at Object.execFileSync (child_process.js:487:13)
at Object.run (/Users/GLB-285/Desktop/ReactProjects/DribbleProject/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cliEntry.js:136:16)
at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli/index.js:117:7)
at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Clean ~/.rncache folder.
2. Download 4 third party library by manual 
   **or**

Re-run the `react-native run-ios` command and wait to print

```
curl: Saved to filename message. 

You should check 100% Received status.
```

**Never press the ctrl+c on build phase.**