# Xcode build commands failed

Tags: xcode, react-native

When I try to build my ReactNative app using Xcode, I get a build error:

```
The following build commands failed:
    PhaseScriptExecution Install\ Third\ Party /Users/attila/Documents/my-mobile-app/ios/build/Build/Intermediates.noindex/React.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/double-conversion.build/Script-190EE32F1E6A43DE00A8543A.sh
(1 failure)
```

It's listed under "double-conversion" in the left pane in Xcode:

[image]

I've reinstalled `node_modules` and made sure my user has read/write permissions for the entire project, but this didn't help.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/46149950/7349445

Comment: The answer there didn't help :(

Comment: I am getting same problem, Please help me is anyone have idea for this.